# While doesnt give me more trainers

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to make a map with available gyms that also shows what exercises they have. So it looks like this:

- Name Gym
- Open spots: (number)
- Logo image of Gym

---

- Time of excercise.
- Image of a dumbel for example
- Trainer

  ---

The part from Time of exercise til Trainer needs to show more than one, I got  like 6 exercises with 6 trainers, and 6 times and 6 different images of exercises to show. I store those in a database; but they don't show up.

Here my code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM forts";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "[";

    $output = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $url = preg_replace("/^http:/i", "https:", $row['url']);

        $sqlmon = "SELECT * FROM gym_trainers WHERE fort_id = " . $row['id'];
        $resultmon = $mysqli->query($sqlmon);
        $mon = $resultmon->fetch_assoc();

        $sqlextra = "SELECT * FROM extrainfo WHERE fort_id = " . $row['id'] . "  ORDER BY last_modified DESC";
        $resultextra = $mysqli->query($sqlextra);
        $extra = $resultextra->fetch_assoc();

            array_push($output, '
                {
                "id": "' . $row['id'] . '",
                "name": "' . htmlspecialchars($row['name']) . '",
                "image": "' . $url . '",
                "team": "' . $team . '",
                "spots": ' . $extra['spots'] . ',
                "exer_time": ' . $mon['time_exerise'] . ',
                "trainer": "' . htmlspecialchars($mon['trainer_name']) . '",
                "exercise_id": ' . $mon['exercise_id'] . ',
                "lat": ' . $row['lat'] . ',
                "lng": ' . $row['lon'] . '

                }
            ');
    }

    echo implode(",", $output);

        echo "]";
```

I think something with this part needs to change, but don't know what:

```
"exer_time": ' . $mon['time_exerise'] . ',
"trainer": "' . htmlspecialchars($mon['trainer_name']) . '",
"exercise_id": ' . $mon['exercise_id'] . ',
```

Comment: Don't write JSON this way, it's not only super ugly, you're doing it wrong. Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and you won't have problems.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman how do you mean, n problems with it, cause i dont see the right way with it.

Comment: You must never assume that your sql queries are successfully executed. You must always check for errors. Since you do not check for sql errors, you do not know what has gone wrong...

Comment: @jh1711, queries are all good, but isnt it nly show one trainer, because of the while loop?

Comment: Smashing JSON together by hand, as you're doing here, is almost always the wrong way to do it. Use the `json_encode` method on a nested array that you've composed with the same structure and it'll always encode properly, no issues. `htmlspecialchars` is completely useless when it comes to JSON encoding, you're mangling things to `&quot;` and presuming it's "working".

Comment: @Shadow everything is running okay.

Comment: @tadman Do you have an example with how i need to do it?

Comment: @AnthonyBijlsma, My comment was based on your question at that time (before the edit(s)). I just pointed out a mistake I spotted. Since you corrected the question, I'll delete the comment soon. Sorry I can't help you with the one trainer problem.

Comment: @AnthonyBijlsma if everything is running ok, then why did you ask this question? Btw, your code did miss the table name from the 3rd query, so the correct behaviour would be apologising for missing the table name from the query.

Comment: @Shadow its not working cause it doesnt show all trainers, only one, and there should be 6 trainers. i dont know what i miss.

Comment: @AnthonyBijlsma, I'm confident that Shadow got to the root of your question. Try to understand the first sentence of the answer. If it helps you add `while ($tmp = $resultmon->fetch_assoc()) var_dump ($tmp);` bellow `$mon = $resultmon->fetch_assoc();`, and analyse the output.

Comment: If you can't be bothered to read the documentation for `json_encode`, which I linked to, or even *try* to use it, which is as simple as `json_encode(array(1,2,3))` I can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

The specific problem is that you fetch only 1 record from the `gym_trainers` table (the `$resultmon->fetch_assoc()` is not in a separate loop).

The wider problem is that you do not use joins. The 3 separate sql queries could be written as

```
select *
from forts f
left join gym_trainers g on f.id=g.fort_id
left join extrainfo e on f.id=g.fort_id
```

In this case you would need a single loop and within the single loop you track if the fort changes.

Comment: And how can i get more records, with it?
I'm now usng the left join method,thanks:)

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: I only fetch 1 from gym_trainers, how do i get more?

Comment: The same way you fetch multiple gyms in your code: fetching the trainers in a loop.

Comment: But how... I'm getting crazy i dont understand, because how can i show more in a row.